# PHP Regex to Capture mm:ss.uuu AND hh:mm:ss.uuu

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to capture the timestamps of some caption files with some luck.

I've managed to get an expression that will partially capture hh:mm:ss.uuu as shown in #910 below, but am unable to figure out how to capture the groups if the optional `h:` or `hh:` is not present.  My work so far is at https://regex101.com/r/4QWySg/1.  As you can see, it's only capturing after the first hour is encountered.

Any help is appreciated :)

```
909
59:48.420 --> 1:00:06.450
THERE SHOULD BE AN OPTION TO UNMUTE DO

910
1:00:06.460 --> 1:00:09.870
YOU SEE A MICROPHONE ICON ANYWHERE ON YOUR TEAMS


(^\d+$\R)?(\d{1,2}(?::\d{2}){2}\.\d{2,3})\s*-->\s*(\d{1,2}(?::\d{2}){2}\.\d{2,3})\R((?:[^\r\n]|\r?\n[^\r\n])*)(?:\r?\n\r?\n|$)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your regex and get all matches using this in PHP:

```sh
((?:\d{1,2}:)?\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{2,3})\s*-->\s*((?1))\R(.+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iyXXN1/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `(?:\d{1,2}:)?`: Match optional hour digits followed by `:`
  - `\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{2,3}`: Match `mm:ss.uuu` part
- `)`: End capture group #1
- `\h*-->\h*`: Match `->` surrounded with optional spaces on both sides
- `((?1))`: recurses the 1st **subpattern** i.e. match using same pattern as in group #1. Capture this in group #2
- `\R`: Match any newline
- `(.+)`: Match 1+ of any characters in 3rd capture group for caption

Comment: That's FANTASTIC...I didn't mention in the original question, but I DO need the caption text.  I'll figure it out and get something ugly, but is there an elegant way to add that to your solution?

Comment: I worship regex knowledge like yours!  Why does it not return the second timestamp (to the right of the arrow)

Comment: We just need a capture group for that. Check my updated answer.

Comment: wow...I added another set of parenthesis to accomplish it.  I would buy you lunch and dinner forever, and put your kids thru college to be able to pick your brain for this knowledge.  THANK you!

Comment: Glad it worked out and thanks so much for the kind words. We are here to help each other. Please consider marking answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to edit it to fit your other specifications (such as the \r\n stuff towards the end of your work so far), but this identifies all of the time stamps and post/caption numbers in your example:

```
(^\d+$\R)?(^\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}|^\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})\s*-->\s*(\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}|\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})
```

I used the pipe | to create an or statement that matched both expected timestamp formats.